# Why is Sqlite3::prepare() throwing an error on my UPDATE... FROM statement despite valid syntax?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have a SQL statement that was working fine when prepared in PHP@5.6, but in an upgrade to 7.3.24 (macOS default on Big Sur), this prepared statement fails now:

```
UPDATE results 
            SET comment = :comment 
            FROM (
                SELECT expected
                        , status
                FROM results
                WHERE report_id = :prevReportID
            ) AS s
            WHERE results.report_id = :workingReportID
            AND results.status = s.status
```

I've verified that sqlite will accept this syntax on the command line, but fails in the call to `prepare`:

```
SQLite3::prepare(): Unable to prepare
statement: 1, near \"FROM\": syntax error",
                "code": 2,
                "file": "/Volumes/Data/web/database.php:157",
                "trace": [
                   
"{\"function\":\"{closure}\",\"args\":[2,\"SQLite3::prepare(): Unable
to prepare statement: 1, near \\\"FROM\\\": syntax
error\",\"/Volumes/Data/web/database.php\",157,{\"sql\":\"UPDATE
results \\n            SET comment = :comment \\n            FROM (\\n
               SELECT expected\\n                        , status\\n  
             FROM results\\n                WHERE report_id =
:prevReportID\\n            ) AS s\\n            WHERE
results.report_id = :workingReportID\\n            AND results.status
= s.status\"}]}",
                    "/Volumes/Data/web/database.php:157",
```

Where `database.php:157` is:

```php
class CommonDB extends SQLite3
    {
    ...
    function prepare($sql)
        {
            return parent::prepare($sql);
        }
    ...
```

The sqlite driver (both CLI and used in php) is 3.35.4 (from homebrew)

Comment: Check again. Execute `select sqlite_version();`

Comment: Oh, lame. 3.28.0. Is there a way to get the native php to use the updated driver?

Comment: I can't help you with that. But I believe your code can be written without the `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax which was introduced in 3.33.0, because actually you don't need this self join.

Comment: The real query is more complicated than this contrived example. Part of the problem I was facing was that using an installed version of PHP 7.4 from homebrew, while using the updated sqlite driver of 3.35, would be unbearably slow. I found an issue in the query that wasn't occurring in previous versions of the driver (the query plan was created or executed differently), and once the query was modified, the updated version of PHP with the updated version of the sqlite driver became useable.